# Binding of label text from ViewModel not working

Tags: xaml, data-binding, binding, maui, datacontext

I am learning .NET MAUI at the moment, and I have run into an issue with data binding. I have read the section on data binding on the Microsoft docs, but I am still none the wiser of why it isn't working.

I can display the button and the second label. However as soon as I bind it to a property on the view model it does not display. If I use the Binding . it displays the MauiTestApp.ViewModel.MainViewModel. What I can glean from that is that the Data context is correct, and that I should just be able to access the property's.

Here is my View Model:

```cs
using MauiTestApp.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MauiTestApp.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>();
        public String s = "Hello world";
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Monkeys.Add(new Monkey("Bob", 20));
            Monkeys.Add(new Monkey("Steve", 10));
            Monkeys.Add(new Monkey("Joey", 14));
        }
    
        public void AddMonkey()
        {
            Monkeys.Add(new Monkey("Harry", 23));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTestApp"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MauiTestApp.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiTestApp.Model"
             x:Class="MauiTestApp.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Text="Press me" Pressed="Button_Pressed"></Button>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding s}" TextColor="Purple" ></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Hello world" TextColor="Purple"></Label>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

And the XAML code behind:

```cs
namespace MauiTestApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainViewModel viewModel;
        public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = vm;
        }

        private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             viewModel.AddMonkey();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if it is a basic question, but I am completely stuck at this point.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see any Text in the Label is because it is not a property. You need to use MVVM Toolkit to make your life easier. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features#source-generators)

So your binding in the ViewModel should look like this

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
private string s = "Hello world";
```

Not that it is a private field with a small s. With the ObservableProperty it is generated into a proper Property that is public and assigned using capital S. Important to always do this. Never use the private field. Always the property.

Now there are a lot of problems with your code in general so if you don't mind I will give you a possible solution to what I could translate from your code. I hope it helps.

Firstly, your complete viewmodel can look like this. Notice the [Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm-community-toolkit-features#relaycommand-and-asyncrelaycommand) with the `[RelayCommand]`. It will take your method and make it into a bindable command. Also it follow a naming convention. So it must never end with command. To bind to it we add Command in the view. By doing this we decouple our viewmodel from all reference to MUAI references.

```cs
public partial class MonkeyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Monkey> _monkeys;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string s = "Hello world";

    public MonkeyViewModel()
    {
        Monkeys = new()
        {
            new Monkey
            {
                Name = "Bob",
                Location = 20
            },
            new Monkey
                              {
                Name = "Steve",
                Location = 10
                },
            new Monkey
            {
                Name = "Joey",
                Location = 14
            },
        };
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void AddMonkey()
    {
        var harryMonkey = new Monkey
        {
            Name = "Harry",
            Location = 23
        };

        Monkeys.Add(harryMonkey);
    }
}
```

If we look at your view. It could look like this, showing a list of moneys and your buttons.

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <CollectionView EmptyView = "No data" ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Monkey">
                <Grid Padding = "10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Text= "{Binding Location}" />
                    <BoxView
                        Grid.Row= "2"
                        BackgroundColor= "Gray"
                        HeightRequest= "1" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Button
        Command= "{Binding AddMonkeyCommand}"
        Text= "Press me" />
    <Label
        Text= "{Binding S}"
        TextColor= "Purple" />

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

Code Behind. Never forget to bind to your `BindingContext`, either in here or like you did, in the xaml. If not your view will not bind to anything.

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly MonkeyViewModel _monkeyViewModel;
    public MainPage(MonkeyViewModel monkeyViewModel)
    {
        _monkeyViewModel = monkeyViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _monkeyViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I NEED to use fields with a backing value and a {get; set;} with OnPropertyChanged event. And I make it easier by using the Toolkit and it's source generators. 

I had a question about the ```x:DataType="models:Monkey"``` in the DataTemplate. I assume that is needed to tell it what the format of the data it is going to receive. However I was wondering why that would be necessary. Could it not infer this from the bound object?

Thanks again for the help! This is really helped me a lot.

Comment: No, you can do many types of binding, but somehow it need to know where to find the data. Giving the template the model is the easiest way if you have a well structured data model. Read more about relative bindings and so on here:  [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/)

Comment: You only need observables/INPC if you need to dynamically update the UI

Comment: I good point. @Jason. Points for that.

Comment: `DataType` is required for **compiled bindings**.  Without it, it can infer the types but will be less performant

Answer (score 1):

You can only bind to **public properties**

this is not a property

```
public String s = "Hello world";
```

this is

```
public String s { get; } = "Hello world";
```

Comment: Okay thank you. If I remember correctly you could do that in Xamarin. Could be completely wrong as it was many years ago that I played around with it.

Comment: No binding in Xamarin is exactly the same